# creating instance of peewee model returns null None

Tags: python, sql, fastapi, peewee

For some reason I'm in the state of using peewee and this happened:

I've got a big app already and it works everywhere else, I have some Models like this:

```py
class SomeModel(Model):
    day = DateField();
    related_entity_id = IntegerNotNullField();
    info = CharField();
```

as you can see some custom fields but they should work, I created the sql like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "somemodel" (
    "id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "day" DATETIME,
    "related_entity_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "info" VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
```

and when I try to create an Instance of SomeModel like this

```py
some_model_instance = SomeModel(
    <a date from from api put request>
    1 # id from the same request
    "some text info" # from the same request
);
```

I get `some_model_instance == None`

Does somebody know why?

EDIT:

So why ever, my app works with this behavior, and it saves the data but printing the instance still returns `None` and I don't know why

Comment: `IntegerField()` is already NOT NULL by default, just so you know.